# Add new column in Category Product Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products, custom-field

I need to add additional information to the catalog_category_product table.
This information is to be entered and saved in the category product grid, in a column similar to Position.

Task I've successfully completed so far are:

1. Added a new column to the catalog_category_product table.
2. Extended Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product and added a new column to the grid.

[image: Category Product Grid Additional Field]

After this I am stuck, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Code i've implemented so far which outputs the custom field but doesnt not save information into the field.

File: app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Product.php

Function: _prepareCollection

Here i changed joinField to joinTable so I could access all fields in catalog_category_product.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    if ($this->getCategory()->getId()) {
        $this->setDefaultFilter(array('in_category'=>1));
    }
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
        ->addStoreFilter($this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
        ->joinTable(
            'catalog/category_product',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            ['position' => 'position','custom_field' => 'custom_field'],
            'category_id='.(int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0),
            'left');

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    if ($this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
        $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
        if (empty($productIds)) {
            $productIds = 0;
        }
        $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$productIds));
    }

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Function: _prepareColumns

Here I added a new column to display my custom field.

```
    protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    if (!$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
        $this->addColumn('in_category', array(
            'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
            'type'      => 'checkbox',
            'name'      => 'in_category',
            'values'    => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
            'align'     => 'center',
            'index'     => 'entity_id'
        ));
    }
    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
        'sortable'  => true,
        'width'     => '60',
        'index'     => 'entity_id'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name'),
        'index'     => 'name'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('sku', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU'),
        'width'     => '80',
        'index'     => 'sku'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('price', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price'),
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'width'     => '1',
        'currency_code' => (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE),
        'index'     => 'price'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('position', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position'),
        'width'     => '1',
        'type'      => 'number',
        'index'     => 'position',
        'editable'  => !$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()
        //'renderer'  => 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_renderer_input'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('custom_field', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('My Custom Field'),
        'width'     => '1',
        'type'      => 'number',
        'index'     => 'custom_field',
        'editable'  => !$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()
        //'renderer'  => 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_renderer_input'
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your code for steps 1 and 2? It should just be two steps though. So possibly something not quite right https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Programming/Adding-custom-column-in-quot-Categories-gt-Products-in-category/td-p/10093

Comment: @DominicXigen Sure, I have updated my question.

Comment: @PaulDonnelly, how can i achieve same in 2.3.X